# Can't see all results in Windows Search after an update

Tags: windows-10

[image: Windows Search]

After having updated my Windows in October, sometimes when I wish to use Windows Search, I cannot see all the results. For example I can search for 'Snipping Tool', but I cannot see it in search results. However upon clicking enter, it opens normally. Note that I have Internet search results enabled.

The extent to which Windows Search results are covered varies. Sometimes you can see no results, sometimes it is a few.

Upon clicking on it, it disappears.

Comment: When was the last time it worked?  Has an update been installed?  What update?  So you have Internet search results enabled or disabled?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Here is an article regarding of [Fix problems in Windows Search](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/fix-problems-in-windows-search), you could check if it is helpful to you.

Comment: Sorry for no update. I have done everything including what @Sunny proposed but to no avail, the problem still persists.